# Using oAuth2 with LinkedIn error when redirecting

Tags: c#, .net, linkedin-api, oauth-2.0

### Issue

---

I am calling a URL in my application to the LinkedIn authorisation page but i seem to be getting an error:

```
Request.QueryString = {error=unsupported_response_type&error_description=We+only+support+a+response_type+of+%22code%22+but+you+passed+%22%22&state=DCEeFWf45A53sdfKef424}
```

I have set up my application on the developer page and have retreived the ID and Secret. I then want to direct to the LinkedIn using the URL below:

```
Response.Redirect(string.Format("https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?responsetype=code&client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&state=DCEeFWf45A53sdfKef424&scope=r_basicprofile",APIKey,url));
```

Can anyone see an issue what what i am trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the api it should be `response_type` not `responsetype`.